# Oracle doesn't use the output buffer completely in OCILobRead2, it is possibly fix this?

Tags: database, oracle, encoding, clob, oracle-call-interface

I do a binding to `OCI` for `Rust` and have faced with data reading problem from `[N]CLOB`. For the unclear reason of `OCILobRead[2]` doesn't fill all provided buffer with data though the charset of the server and the client coincide, i.e. no conversion should happen. Nevertheless, Oracle for some reason on each character reserves in the buffer exactly 4 bytes, even when reading the symbols occupying one byte in requested encoding. It leads to the fact that quadruple reservation in the buffer is necessary that is extremely inefficient. Besides, it leads to the fact that in the buffer less than 4 bytes in size nothing is read at all (and in case of the Greek characters, for example, even 7 bytes insufficiently for their reading and on Windows using such buffer lead to crashing of application. And on *nixes in that case Oracle returns the number of the read bytes - 0, and number of the read characters - 1. WTF??? However if to increase the buffer size, then after reading the character occupies in it only 4 bytes (UTF-8 encoding)).

I see that Oracle tries not to break one character in the middle of the byte sequence in requested encoding (thus, the buffer is always filled or Nth bytes per character, or 0 bytes), but it do this in strange way.

Whether there is an opportunity to force Oracle to use the buffer to the maximum? Perhaps, somewhere else it is necessary to specify the encoding? I, apparently, have tried already all options and nothing helps.

The server and client encoding are same - `AL32UTF8`. Here approximately so there is a sequence of calls of OCI (actual code too long and complicated to demonstrate here, but you can find complete test code in [my repo](https://github.com/Mingun/rust-oci/blob/master/tests/lob.rs#L88). Some knownledge or Rust programming language is requiredю Test data prepared in [script](https://github.com/Mingun/rust-oci/blob/master/.travis/oracle/prepare.sql#L152-L172)):

```
ub2 encoding = 873;// AL32UTF8, strange, but there no define constants in API
//              For:   CLOB      NCLOB
OCIEnvNlsCreate(..., encoding, encoding);
...
OCIStmtPrepare2(...);
OCILobLocator* lob;
OCIDefineByPos(..., &lob, ...);
OCIExecute(...);
OCIStmtFetch2(...);

char buf[4];
// request read to end of CLOB
ub8 bytes = 0;
ub8 chars = 0;
OCILobRead2(..., lob,
  &bytes, &chars,
  1, &buf, 4,
  OCI_FIRST_PIECE,
  0, 0,// callbacks not used
  encoding, SQLCS_IMPLICIT
);
// when CLOB contains "0123456789" this call read only "0", not "0123"
// though the place in the buffer is enough and oracle knows about it
```

Comment: Is this really a problem? Usually you want to reduce the amount of round-trips between app and db. So you call OCILobGetChunkSize and prepare a buffer of appropriate size.

Comment: Charset conversion takes place on clients side. The database does not know how will be the string converted, possibly you might convert it into UCS-32. The database server knows only the size of receiveng memory buffer. This was ok, until multibyte charsets were introduced. It is not too handy, byt anyway you do not want to read CLOBs char by char.

Comment: > So you call OCILobGetChunkSize and prepare a buffer of appropriate size.


I write a library, not application, therefore users of library shall receive the expected behavior. It seems that it is necessary to rely on comments and to hope that users won't shoot to themselves at a leg

Oracle API reads CLOBs only character-by-character. In it and the problem - even if is enough place in a buffer, the server is too pessimistic it uses. In a extrime case in the buffer generally nothing will be written though could, or on Windows there will be a crash of the application that is no good at all

Comment: Sorry for formatting - markdown not work for some reason and there no preview :(.

Comment: I also wrote a library. I hid this behaviour from library user. The receiving buffer belongs to a library not to an application.

Comment: I can confirm this. However, in Oracle 23c it works as expected. So Oracle must have fixed that problem somewhere between version 18 and version 23. I have no access to their knowledge base, so I cannot find out more.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the parameter 'bufl' to 4, which is expressed in bytes. Thus oracle client only retrieve 1 utf8 char ( as it can take up to 4 bytes).  The function behavior seems logical to me.

Comment: > as it can take up to 4 bytes

Can, but not take. Oracle works not with abstract characters but with concretic. For example, when I using UTF-16, it correctly returns as much characters, as possible both surrogate pairs, and normal symbols. So why UTF-8 must be different? Server counts characters when prepare answer to client (because it is the only way not to get on the middle of the character) and known, how many bytes it fill in buffer. So why it can't fill byffer as much as possible?

Comment: > Server counts characters when prepare answer to client.
No it does not. Charset conversion takes place on client side :(. The server only knows the size of the receiver's input buffer, not the  amount of chars to be read. Until the multi-byte charsets were introduced it made sense.

Comment: The server does not know caller's target charset.

Comment: @ibre5041 Also there are no methods to tell the server the encoding of the client? No charset attribute of some handle?

Comment: imho not. they decided to to offload server cpu usage and therefore charset conversion takes place client side. before unicode, it was not necessary.
for example the InstantClient works only with databases natively encoded in ISO Latin1 and AL32UTF-8. It can not "talk" with other databases.